# Getting a texture from IOSurface in Metal

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, metal

I'm trying to get a texture id from metal surface.

I have two problems
1. That function is not defined

```
GLint glTextureID = CGLTexImageIOSurface2D(self.mEAGLContext, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA , textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RGBA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ioSurface, 0);
```

I tried to include it #import OpenGL/CGLIOSurface.h 
but xcode doesn't recognize it, it's not there.

Are there any other methods to obtain a texture id from an iosurface in ios, metal ?

Comment: The title of this question says it is related Metal, but the question seems to have something to do with OpenGL and OpenCL. What are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

In my software, the following line pulls in the requested function:

```
#include <OpenGL/CGLIOSurface.h>
```

This header file is at the following location in my xcode installation:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CGLIOSurface.h

Note that I am using the MacOS SDK.  Perhaps iOS doesn't support GL/IOSurface sharing?